# How can I get a full string that contains a substring in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

For example:

I have a array

```
const tags = ['size-1', 'size-2', 'discount-xyz']
```

In this case to check if I have a substring with **discount** in it, I have converted the array to a string

```
const arrayToString = tags.toString();
```

The output:

```
const tagsArrayToString = size-1,size-2,discount-wyx;
```

And I check if with a IF statement like this:

```
if ( tagsArrayToString.indexOf("discount") !== -1 ) { doSomething }
```

So far so good. But how can I get the full String like **"discount-xyz"**?

Comment: Don't convert to a string. Find each item that matches. You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't convert the `tags` array to a string - you already have the strings nice and separated, and this would only make things harder.

Instead, you could `filter` the array:

```js
const filteredTags = tags.filter(t => t.includes('discount'));
```

Or, if you know there's just one such string, you could use `find` to get it:

```js
const relevantTag = tags.find(t => t.includes('discount'));
```

Comment: Thanks @mureinik
In this case, if I have multiples tags arrays, should I change something?

Comment: @GêMedina not sure I understand this followup question. Could you post it as a full question with the relevant code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

Find the index of the discount tag using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method, in turn find the tag itself via the index of the array.

```
const index = tags.findIndex(t => t.indexOf('discount') !== -1);
const discountTag = tags[index];
```